When I try to export this file as a.usdz, would the hand tracking features be intact? I'm utilising hand tracking to place objects in scene view
Im showing objet on wrist point of hand which we will get from hand tracking in ARKit provided by apple.
I wanted export that scene view as .usdz file?
So my question is when exporting that file can i get hand tracking features in that file or not ?
If not what data i get from .usdz file when export?
